# Как указать в XML Schema появление только одного из нескольких элементов

Tags: xml, lxml

Доброго времени суток!
Есть xml-файл со след. содержимым:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<packet timestamp='2012-02-13 12:50:11.269146' id='97b20aee-5606-11e1-a55c-0050fc9bb1bb'>
    <opensession>
        ...
    </opensession>
</packet>
```

Но элемент `<packet>` может содержать либо вложенный элемент `<opensession>` либо `<closesession>`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это описать в XML Schema?

На данный момент имеется valid.xsd след. содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="packet" type="PacketType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="PacketType">
        <xsd:attribute name="timestamp" type="xsd:date"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string"/>

    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось довольно просто:

```
...
    <xsd:choise>
        <xsd:element name="one" />
        <xsd:element name="two" />
        ...
    </xsd:choice>
...
```

`<choise>` - Позволяет присутствовать в элементе-контейнере одному-единственному элементу выбранной группы.

P.S. Хороший справочник на рус. языке по схемам XML (XSD) можно найти [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256235(v=vs.90).aspx).